# Proof of uniqueness of Laplace Transform

Tags: proof-explanation, laplace-transform

I'm studying proof of the uniqueness of the Laplace Transform and I have some problems with understanding it.

[Here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~marshall/math_135/UniqueLaplace.pdf)  is the proof.

Why can we change $u^{n}$ for polynomial $p(u)$?  What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $p(u)=\sum_{n=0}^k a_n u^n.$ Now use $(1)$ of the proof and linearity of integral.

Comment: Okay, but it's equal $$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{a_n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{k+1}.$$ So why are we replacing it by $u^n$. Sorry, I can't see it

Comment: I don't understand your question. $$\int_0^1 h(u)p(u)=\sum_{n=0}^k a_n\int_0^1 h(u)u^n\, du=0$$